# Jquery datatable input textbox to column

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using jquery datatable and below is the code. It is filled data successfully to datatable when clicking button. there is no problem in it.

```
  table = $('#customerMarkuptbl').DataTable({
            data: null,
            columns: [                           
                        { title: "CarrierID ", "data": "CarrierID", visible: false },
                        { title: "Carrier Service ID ", "data": "CarrierServiceID", visible: false },
                        { title: "Carrier ", "data": "CarrierName" },
                        { title: "Carrier Service", "data": "CarrierServiceName" },
                        {
                            title: "Markup ", "data": "MarkupValue",
                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<input class="form-control" id="Markup" name="Markup" type="text"  value = ' + row.MarkupValue + '  >';
                            }
                        },
            ]
        });
```

It is added a textbox column to the table. Then the user change text box value and it sends as json string to the server.

```
var ObjMarkup = $('#customerMarkuptbl').DataTable().data().toArray();
```

The issue is ObjMarkup doesnt contain changes of textboxes. It is always showing as 0. (Default it is set to 0 when retrieve data to datatable)

Below Example has sample row details which is outcome of "ObjMarkup". In below case I change the value of textbox and it not assign to the "ObjMarkup" variable.

> Eg: CarrierID:42 CarrierName:"Test carrier" CarrierServiceID:625
>   CarrierServiceName:"Full load" MarkupValue:0

So whats the problem in this? Is there any solution? Why cant get textbox value to array?

Answer (score 3):

Add a class to your input in the Render function.  I'll use trackInput for my example.

```
  table = $('#customerMarkuptbl').DataTable({
            data: null,
            columns: [                           
                        { title: "CarrierID ", "data": "CarrierID", visible: false },
                        { title: "Carrier Service ID ", "data": "CarrierServiceID", visible: false },
                        { title: "Carrier ", "data": "CarrierName" },
                        { title: "Carrier Service", "data": "CarrierServiceName" },
                        {
                            title: "Markup ", "data": "MarkupValue",
                            render: function (data, type, row) {
                                return '<input class="form-control trackInput" id="Markup" name="Markup" type="text"  value = ' + row.MarkupValue + '  >';
                            }
                        },
            ],
    "drawCallback": function( settings ) {
                  $(".trackInput").on("change",function(){
                       var $row = $(this).parents("tr");
                       var rowData = table.row($row).data();

                       rowData.MarkupValue = $(this).val();


                  })
            }
        });
```

Now

```
var ObjMarkup = $('#customerMarkuptbl').DataTable().data().toArray();
```

will give the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure I understand what happen when "*user change text box value and it sends as json string to the server*" but you cannot retrieve the dynamic values of `<input>`'s (regardless of type) through `data()`. `data()` will only return the original values, there is no internal logic where changing the `<input>` also changes the underlying dataset.

So you must do that by yourself. Here is an example retrieving the dynamic value of an `<input>` inserted to the first column by a `render()` callback as above :

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var $row = table.row(this).nodes().to$(),
      currentInputValue = $row.find('td:eq(0) input').val()
  console.log(currentInputValue)
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vp2j3mcd/**

As mentioned I am not quite sure what you are trying to do, cannot replicate totally. But you could take the above code and

```
var ObjMarkup = $('#customerMarkuptbl').DataTable().data().toArray();
ObjMarkup.MarkupValue = currentInputValue
//...send (I guess)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get the value:

```
table.cell(rowIdx,colIndx).nodes().to$().find('input').val()
```