# How can I put a selectbox in a column inside a jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, datatables

In the following datatable, I want to put the selectbox into the "Durum" column. How do I do this and how do I get the option value I selected? I want to use a selectbox inside my datatable. Thank you for help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FirmaTable").show();
  table = $("#FirmaTable").DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: ['excel', 'print'],
    lengthChange: false,
    searching: false,
    paging: false,

    "ajax": {
      "url": "/Raporlama/DataVeri",
      "type": "GET",
      "datatype": "json"

    },

    "columns": [

      {
        "data": "Kullanici"
      },
      {
        "data": "VerildigiTarih"
      },
      {
        "data": "EkBilgi"
      },
      {
        "data": "KargoBilgisi"
      },
      {
        "data": "Firma"
      },
      {
        "data": "Adres"
      },
      {
        "data": "AdresOpsiyonlu"
      },
      {
        "data": "TeslimEdilen"
      },
      {
        "data": "Durum"
      }

    ]
  });

});
```

```html
<table id="FirmaTable" class="display compact" style="display:none">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Kullanici</th>
      <th>Verildigi Tarih</th>
      <th>Ek Bilgi</th>
      <th>Kargo Bilgisi</th>
      <th>Firma</th>
      <th>Adres</th>
      <th>Adres Opsiyonlu</th>
      <th>Teslim Edilecek Kişi</th>
      <th>Durum</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38366213/jquery-datatable-input-textbox-to-column

Comment: Welcome boss keep doing keep growing :)